# Modulo Arithmetic With Exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having some trouble with the following modular arithmetic question.

> Compute the following, $$4^{22222}\hspace{0.1cm}\text{mod 121}$$

So far I have the following working.

By Fermat's Little Theorem,

$$4^{120} \equiv 1\hspace{0.1cm}\text{mod 121}$$

$$4^{22222}\equiv (4^{120})^{185} \cdot 4^{22}$$

I'm not sure where to go next. I can't see any possible route.

Comment: Be careful, when you deal with Fermat's Little Theorem you should use prime numbers. For instance $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\mbox{mod}~p)$ where $p$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 3):

Using Euler Totient Theorem, $$\phi(121)=11\cdot10$$

and $$22222\equiv2\pmod{110}$$

For $(a,11)=1$
$$a^{22222}\equiv a^2\pmod{11^2}\phantom{ }$$

Comment: Please edit your answer, I want to choose another arrow...

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, What do you mean?

Comment: Indeed, I can edit the answers too =)